# Sqoop with kerberos security not working in cron , throw GSSException

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, sqoop

When i run sqoop job from edge node , its working fine and able to extract data from oracle, But when i schedule the same job in crontab, it throw kerberos security error.

I found same problem reported in hortonworks site(see the link), but does not have any valid answer.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/61856/kerberos-ticket-error-in-a-cron-job.html

I has valid kerberos ticket before cron job start and its valid for 10 hours, But when i schedule cron job in 5 minutes, it throw kerberos error.

Please suggest, what are the steps need to be followed before starting sqoop import in cron job.

Below is the detailed error message :

> 17/11/23 11:24:17 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException:
>
> ***GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)];***
>
> Host Details : local host is: "ps2pr028380.express-scripts.com/10.221.171.22"; destination host is: "ps2pr028377.express-scripts.com":8020;
>         at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:782)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1558)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1498)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1398)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getDelegationToken(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:980)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:291)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:203)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:185)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getDelegationToken(DFSClient.java:1041)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getDelegationToken(DistributedFileSystem.java:1688)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.collectDelegationTokens(FileSystem.java:549)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.addDelegationTokens(FileSystem.java:527)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.addDelegationTokens(DistributedFileSystem.java:2400)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:140)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:142)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:200)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:173)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:270)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:748)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.importQuery(OracleManager.java:454)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:509)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:720)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:683)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:770)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3200(Client.java:397)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1620)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
>         ... 43 more
>   Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>         at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:413)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:595)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:397)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:762)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:758)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:757)
>         ... 46 more
>   Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
>         at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
>         at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
>         at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
>         at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
>         at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
>         at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
>         at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
>         ... 55 more

Comment: I solved my own question : I added below comment in my script and called this before sqoop start . kinit -kt /home/userName/userName.keytab userName@PROD.DATAHUB.LOCAL

Comment: Add this as an "Answer".  Then come back in two days to self-accept it.

Comment: Thanks Heron for your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own question : I added below comment in my script and called this before sqoop start.

```
 kinit -kt /home/userName/userName.keytab userName@PROD.DATAHUB.LOCAL
```

We are using hortonwork cluster, so they have another solution for this problem, please find the other solution link below

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/149168/sqoop-with-kerberos-security-not-working-in-cron-t.html

Comment: Please self-accept your answer to mark it as Green and better highlight it to others who may stumble upon this in their search results.